# pick particular string from a nested string using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to pick error message from this error string:

```
[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. (8169) (SQLExecDirectW)
```

I just need to give the error:

```
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

to the user. How do i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like

```
s = "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. (8169) (SQLExecDirectW)"
print(s[s.rfind(']')+1: s.find('(')])
```

Comment: works if the error is isolated. does not work if the error is contained more then once in a string (aka finding error inside a log file): `bla [something]text1(bla)\nbla [some other thing]text2(bla)\n` gives you an empty slice

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find multiple occurences of this pattern in a longer text, [@mohammedwazeems's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60826166/7505395) no longer works.

In that case, use regex:

```
import re

regex = r".*](.+?)[(]"   # avoid all until last ] that is followed by captured anything lazyly
                         # that is followed by an open (

log_file = """some text that is fine
[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. (8169) (SQLExecDirectW)
more ok text
[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Fix me error. (8169) (SQLExecDirectW)
more okish text"""

matches = re.finditer(regex, log_file, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:

    if len(match.groups())>0:
        print ( match.group(1))
```

prints :

```
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. 
Fix me error.
```

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/GPWs2a/1

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to use something like this: ```error[error.rfind(']')+1:error.find('(')]```

Comment: @ShadyMBA - if you look for that occurence in text that contains it exactly ONCE - yes. Try finding two to hundred occurences of that in one longer log file ... and you can't. Regex can. In fact https://stackoverflow.com/a/60826166/7505395 will get you NOTHING if you feed it text that contains the error message twice because the slice will look something like [99:43]  (i.e. the first ] from back and first ( from back will target two different messages alltogether and get an empty slice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
error = '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. (8169) (SQLExecDirectW)'
error[error.rfind(']')+1:error.find('(')]
```

That should give:

```
'Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. '
```

Comment: Its not perticular message, it could me aything for example
[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]PickMe. (8169) (SQLExecDirectW)

Comment: he said " this error string" so he's very specific. If he needs it to be more generic then he needs to specify so in his question.